# How to change Device Identity Certificate(SCEP certificate)'s expiration date in OS X Server App(for Profile Manager)

Tags: ios, ios8, certificate, ota, jscep

Now I'm trying to test "Update Profile" button(Settings > General > Profile >  Device Management based on iOS 8.4) and whether update works well or not after Device Identity Certificate (SCEP certificate) was expired as below.

[Screenshot of Update Profile button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLPE9.jpg)

[Screenshot of Expiration Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJzaQ.jpg)

I verified that expiration date can be set in 3rd party SCEP server.
But I can't find any settings for expiration date(at least a current day) from Server App of Mac OS X Server. (SCEP function is combined to Server App)

In this status, I have to wait for a year to see it from finishing a device enrollment.

I really want to know how to change SCEP certificate's expiration date even in source level.

Is there somebody can tell me how? Please help me.

Thanks.